# How to check if IIS is in 32bit or 64bit mode

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

I'm trying to deploy a site to a 64bit OS. I'm deploying to IIS6. The site was developed on a 32bit server. The site deployed correctly however it's trying to access a COM component and that is failing.

I believe the error is occurring because the COM component is a 64bit version on the 64bit OS. And IIS6 is running in 32bit mode on the 64bit server.

I'd like to confirm this but I can't seem to find a definitive way to check if IIS6 is in 32bit mode or 64bit mode.

Would someone know the best way to check if IIS6 is in 64bit or 32bit mode?

EDIT: I'm using IIS6

Comment: You have access to the server? or do you mean programmatically check?

Comment: I have access to the server. So through whatever means on the server itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

which version of IIS? to check it manually just click the application pool, in properties or advanced properties

if you need to check it programatically you can do it through WMI:

/LM/W3SVC namespace on the

IIsWebService class

Enable32BitAppOnWin64 property

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5d306956-b2a2-4708-9bb9-72a395d474bb.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: We are sorry, the page you requested cannot be found. 

The URL may be misspelled or the page you're looking for is no longer available.

Answer (score 72):

Go to IIS Manager -> Application Pools -> select the app pool you want and -> Advanced Settings.

In there there's a setting called "Enable 32-bit Applications". If that's true, that means the worker process is forced to run in 32-bit. If the setting is false, then the app pool is running in 64-bit mode.

Also you can open up Task Manager and check `w3wp.exe`. If it's shown as `w3wp*32.exe` then it's 32-bit.

More info [here](http://tipila.com/tips/54/how-to-check-if-iis-7-is-running-in-32-bit-mode-or-64-bit-mode-in-64bit-windows).

Answer (score 7):

In .NET code (pre-V4) you can check the size of an `IntPtr` instance.

In V4 check `Environment.Is64BitProcess` and `Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem` properties.

Answer (score 7):

Go to IIS using : Run command -> type "inetmgr" see the Application pool settings,
Select the Framework of your application
Click on Advance Setting on the right Menu option
See the "Enable 32-Bit Application" option

> If "Enable 32-Bit Application" - "TRUE" then your application executes
>   in 32 bit, If "FALSE" then it executes in 64 Bit

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For IIS6 you can run this command:

C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts> cscript adsutil.vbs GET W3SVC/AppPools/Enable32BitAppOnWin64