# Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, out-of-memory

I got the following problem

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +567
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +192
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +35
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +123

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +11569328
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +485
   System.Web.Configuration.AssemblyInfo.get_AssemblyInternal() +79
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +337
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods() +280
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +1167

[HttpException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +11702064
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +141
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +4870277
```

I didn't change the code ? what is this problem mean ,, as I see there is no more declaration about the error

Comment: What were you doing before this exception started to occur?

Comment: which event triggered this error.say for example insert,select,etc..

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This problem usually occurs when some process such as loading huge data to memory stream and your system memory is not capable of storing so much of data. Try clearing temp folder by giving the command

> start -> run -> %temp%

Comment: Try checking your processes and see when you run your blank page, the memory hike. Check if your system has enough memory to load a page. Seems it crashes on page init itself.

Comment: Read this. It's great article! http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-system-outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp-net.aspx

Comment: in my temp folder only f files, I don't think this issue because of the temp file.

Answer (score 17):

Another thing to try is

Tools -> Options -> search for *IIS* -> tick *Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects*.

[image: Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express for web sites and projects screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your guidance it was working fine, could you please provide the server configuration to fix in the production site.

Comment: @Selva In production it would be running under IIS, so you need to check the Application Pool the application is running under.  e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804040/how-to-check-if-iis-is-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode

Comment: For those having their project deployed on Azure App Service, the same can be done from the `Configuration blade -> General Settings -> Platform` and set it to 64bit

Answer (score 14):

**Running in Debug Mode**

When you're developing and debugging an application, you will typically run with the debug attribute in the web.config file set to true and your DLLs compiled in debug mode. However, before you deploy your application to test or to production, you should compile your components in release mode and set the debug attribute to false.

ASP.NET works differently on many levels when running in debug mode. In fact, when you are running in debug mode, the GC will allow your objects to remain alive longer (until the end of the scope) so you will always see higher memory usage when running in debug mode.

Another often unrealized side-effect of running in debug mode is that client scripts served via the webresource.axd and scriptresource.axd handlers will not be cached. That means that each client request will have to download any scripts (such as ASP.NET AJAX scripts) instead of taking advantage of client-side caching. This can lead to a substantial performance hit.

Source: http://blogs.iis.net/webtopics/archive/2009/05/22/troubleshooting-system-outofmemoryexceptions-in-asp-net.aspx

Answer (score 7):

I just restarted Visual Studio and did IISRESET which solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using IIS Express, select `Show All Application` from IIS Express in the task bar notification area, then select `Stop All`.

Now re-run your application.