# How to fix error: "Framework resource extraction failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

I have a project of UWP application. The project is large, many pages, resources, classes and other. When **compiling**, I have everything built, but at the end I have compilation error:

```
C:\Users\user\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk\2.2.9\tools\CoreRuntime\Microsoft.Net.CoreRuntime.targets(195,9): error : Framework resource extraction failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

The error is after everything is built successfully - i have:  SpiderIntelligence -> E:\Project\SpiderAI\SpiderIntelligence\SpiderIntelligence\bin\x64\Debug\SpiderIntelligence.exe

I have tried different versions of platforms: microsoft.net.uwpcoreruntimesdk - 2.2.3 up to 2.2.9,
Different target platforms, different build configurations. I have cleared the solution, deleted BIN && OBJ folders. No effect...

I have powerful machine with 48GB of RAM, so this is not RAM issue. Everything installed should be 64 bit.

Please help me to diagnose this problem. I am stopped with the solution, I have now ideas what to do with this error.

UPDATE: I have found that core of the problem is Microsoft.ML library. If I remove ML.NET from the solution - everything is perfect! It seems it is BUG...

Comment: You could check this guide to debugging .net Out of memory error : https://blog.elmah.io/debugging-system-outofmemoryexception-using-net-tools/

Comment: Thanks for the response. My error is compilation error - I am not able to debug anything...

Comment: These System.OutOfMemoryExceptions can be really nasty to chase down.  As you have already stated, it has nothing to do with the ram available on your machine. (Although 48GB?!?!? WOW!).  You would get the same error on a machine with 8GB of ram. .NET sets its own limitations, and figuring out which one you are bumping up against can be a real challange.  Question: Does it tell you which particular project the error is hapening in? And if so, what kind of project is it?

Comment: also, lots of good tips here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438281/exception-of-type-system-outofmemoryexception-was-thrown

Comment: I used a WinUI3 app source code which is working fine. The moment i add "Microsoft.ML" from Nuget i get "Framework resource extraction failed" error. I tried many versions but the latest tried is "2.0.0-preview.22313.1". OS is Win11. VS is 17.3.0 Preview 1.1. Source code is in VB.NET (Pls note the arrays start with 0 index in VB)