# How can I enable "URL Rewrite" Module in IIS 8.5 in Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, url-rewrite-module, iis-8.5

I have windows server 2012 and I have installed the IIS 8.5 but I could not see the URL rewrite module. How can I enable or install?

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Download it from here:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

or if you already have Web Platform Installer on your machine you can install it from there.

Comment: And don't forget to close and reopen the IIS Manager.
After the installation the new icon is only visible, after reopening. (refresh won't work)

Comment: From experience: sometimes you need to uninstall it (Add/Remove Programs or Uninstall a Program in the control panel) and then install it again to get it to work. Don't know why it wasn't working, but this fixed it for me.

Comment: Is it any way to script this?

Comment: do you mean the installation? launch CMD/promt with "Run as administrator", then type
msiexec /I rewrite_2.0_rtw_x64.msi

Comment: i have about 40 hours into this (very embarrassed)  Uninstall / reinstall as Jo said worked--no clue why.

Answer (score 23):

**Worth mentioning:** you should download the **x64** version!

From the main download page (https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) click **"additional downloads"** (under the main download button) and download the x64 version (because for some reason - the default download version is x86)

Answer (score 13):

- First, install the URL Rewrite from a download or from the Web Platform Installer.
- Second, restart IIS.
- And, finally, close IIS and open again.

The last step worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

Thought I'd give a full answer combining some of the possible intricacies required for completeness.

1. Check if you have [32-bit or 64-bit IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804040/how-to-check-if-iis-is-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode/16232432#16232432) installed:

   - Go to IIS Manager → Application Pools, choose the appropriate app pool then Advanced Settings.
   - Check the setting "Enable 32-bit Applications". If that's true, that means the worker process is forced to run in 32-bit. If the
     setting is false, then the app pool is running in 64-bit mode.
   - You can also open up Task Manager and check `w3wp.exe`. If it's showing as `w3wp*32.exe` then it's 32-bit.
2. Download the appropriate version here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite#additionalDownloads.
3. Install it.
4. Close and reopen IIS Manager to ensure the URL Rewrite module appears.