# Slim error 404 route

Tags: php, rest, iis, web-config, slim

My app giving error (404 not found) when try access route:

```
$app->get('/test/', function () { 
  echo "Hello, World! test"; 
});
```

But is ok, when try access:

```
$app->get('/', function () { 
  echo "Hello, World!"; 
});
```

Need configure Allowoverride All ? 
how i can do it, using web.config IIS ?]

UPDATE..
i create web.config file with code:
Not using htaccess now, only web.config.. but still not working

**URL Rewrite Module Error.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="slim" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Your `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` condition means that if the folder exists, do not rewrite.  From your `$app->get()` code, it is clear that the folder/path `/test/` either does not exist, or does not have proper permissions. Also, you are trying to use `.htaccess` on an IIS server -- you might want to look [translate htaccess content to iis webconfig](https://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig)

Comment: @KraangPrime update check plz

Comment: Do you have the [rewrite module installed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25998019/3504007) and enabled ?

Comment: i think not.. how do it plz?

Comment: See the link in my last comment.  That is a link to a solution which shows how to install it.

Comment: Yes is active and installed.. =/

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED ;D

i believe was php (5.4.x) version and doctrine need (5.5.x +)

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the problem. If you could expand on this solution so that it may help someone else with the same problem, that would be useful.  I also added the `php` tag to your question.

Comment: yep ill do it, now the problem is error 405 when try PUT, and sometimes error 500 when trying POST.. with slim