# IIS 8 Rewrite Rules for Folder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have Asp.Net project. My project physical path structure as **/htdocs/site1/...**

I would like to change this url request as **/site1/...**

I have put below codes into to webconfig but it is not working. Currently IIS 8 rewrite extension installed on web server

```
 <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="htdocs_remove">
          <match url="/htdocs/site1/" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/site1/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Is "htdocs" actually in your site url i.e. `http://example.com/htdocs/site1`  ?

Comment: @Kev basically I am getting widget page into parent page in **site1** folder like this **@RenderPage("/htdocs/widgets/page1.cshtml")** my actually url is http://example.com/htdocs/site1/index.cshtml

Answer (score -1):

Restart IIS and try again. If it fails to work then follow this [ref-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410067/iis-url-rewrite-and-web-config) and [ref-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25997830/how-can-i-enable-url-rewrite-module-in-iis-8-5-in-server-2012).